# mongodb join collection without nested result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have two collections on which I want to do a query. Based on some condition it should return the results from both the collections in separate objects. I have looked for online solutions but didn't find anything.

sample

```
col1: [
  {
    _id: "st_123",
    stud_num: 123,
    school: "sc_123"
  },
  {
    _id: "st_234",
    stud_num: 123,
    school: "sc_234"
  },
  {
    _id: "st_345",
    stud_num: 123,
    school: "sc_345"
  }
]

col2: [
  {
    _id: "f_123",
    stud_health_id: "st_123",
    schoolYear: "sy123",
    fk_school: "sc_123"
  },
  {
    _id: "f_234",
    stud_health_id: "st_234",
    schoolYear: "sy234",
    fk_school: "sc_234"
  },
  {
    _id: "f_345",
    stud_health_id: "st_234",
    schoolYear: "sy234",
    fk_school: "sc_237"
  }
]
```

When I send some filter like `{ std_id: 'st_123', school_id: 'sc_123' }`, it should return this.

```
[
{
    _id: "st_123",
    stud_num: 123,
    school: "sc_123"
},
{
    _id: "f_123",
    stud_health_id: "st_123",
    schoolYear: "sy123",
    fk_school: "sc_123"
},
```

]

The request param `std_id` matches with col1 _id and col2 stud_health_id. The `school_id` matches with col1 school and col2 fk_school. The objective of this is to merge the two so it can be also paginated. Is there any way this can be done with aggregation. Both of the collections will have thousands of record. I have tried lookup but that returns a nested array inside of col1 documents.

Comment: Perhaps the `$unionWith` aggregation stage is applicable here?

Comment: Yes that will do it. Read about it here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      a: {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$col1",
          "$col2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      a: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$a",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this._id",
                  "st_123"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.school",
                  "sc_123"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$a"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$a"
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/rRzubuZXW8W